AJAX AutocompleteExtender added from ASP.NET code behind does not work
I add multiple AJAX AutocompleteExtenders from code behind.
Only one of them is working properly.
When I check the HTML page I find one  object created (for the working extender).
I can't figure out why this happens.
I have traced the code and the code behind is running properly generating the objects as expected with unique ID's as expected.
This is the C# code which generates the Extenders:
          var acl = new AjaxControlToolkit.AutoCompleteExtender();
          acl.TargetControlID = tbc.ID;
          acl.ID = $"ACE_{partno}_{r.ParameterNo}";
          acl.BehaviorID = acl.ID;
          acl.ServiceMethod = "GetColors";
          acl.MinimumPrefixLength = 1;
          acl.CompletionInterval = 100;
          acl.EnableCaching = false;
          acl.CompletionSetCount = 10;
          acl.FirstRowSelected = false;
          acl.ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem = true;
          acl.CompletionListCssClass = "autocomplete_completionListElement";

The code generates two extenders with ID ACE_5_3 and ACE_5_5
At the end of body only one ul is generated:
<ul id="ACE_5_3_completionListElem" class="autocomplete_completionListElement" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;"></ul>

This is the only difference I have found between working and non working extenders.

We can't guess what's going on with tis partial code. The AJAX toolkit is beyond ancient (more than 1 decade old) and only useful for WebForms applications that weren't modified to use Javascript. Even the people that did use it 10-15 years ago won't remember how it worked. And wouldn't use it for any reason either

In any case you only posted code that creates one extender and doesn't seem to store it anywhere. The extenders were meant to be used as tags. If you create them programmatically, you need to ensure they're added to the page's components. On the other hand, if you just use HTML and and just fetch and json in a Javascript block, you can retrieve. If the number of items is small you could even use HTML's datalist and get autocompletion without any extra code, apart from the code that generates the <option> elements

It's an old site I'm doing some updates on.
I do add the control, but that line wasn't in my code:
C2.Controls.Add(acl);
C2 is a cell in a table.

Try to avoid injecting such controls. I still do boatloads of webforms work, and I am rather fond of that development system. However, when designing software, I near ALWAYS take handstands to avoid a code choice in which you have to inject controls. And in 9 out of 10 cases, I'm able to cook up designs which avoid controls injections. Those AJ controls also have to pull resource (JavaScript) files, and thus not only are controls being injected, but the page has to know how to correctly pull in a bunch of JavaScript code for you.  It's just a bad idea. Place controls in the markup already.
